# Ghidra Indexing C quad word

Tags: c, ghidra

There's this Ghidra decompiled C code.

I understand that local_60 is a quad word, but I don't understand indexing it

What does `local_60._3_1_` refer to here?

```
  local_60 = 0x6c46575935676a5a;
  local_28 = 0x7945474e3563544f;
  printf("Enter access code: ");
  __isoc99_scanf(&DAT_0010201c,&DAT_001040c0);
  if ((((DAT_001040c0 == 'f') && (DAT_001040c1 == 'b')) && (DAT_001040c2 == local_60._3_1_)) &&
     ((DAT_001040c3 == '6' && (DAT_001040c4 == local_28._2_1_)))) {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can usually click on the part of decompiled C code and highlight what part of original assembly produced it, this could help you understand what ghidra means by _3_1_ and _2_1_.

From my experience, the _X_Y_ syntax usually means that the code tries to "index" into an integer like an array, by taking a value of a single byte out of 8 into account. In addition to that, if you inspect byte values from the two constants `0x6c46575935676a5a` and `0x7945474e3563544f` you may notice that all the bytes are proper ASCII characters. These two things would suggest that local_60 and local_28 should instead be `char[8]` instead of integers. You should be able to right-click on the variable declarations and change their type manually, which may make code more readable by changing syntax into array indexing and array initialization.

Comment: Hot damn! Thank you so much!